# WordPress website down

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I'm new to programming & I have learned how to create websites using WordPress technology. I have created a website [www.popstudio.in](http://www.popstudio.in) and it was working fine before.

Recently when I try to access the website, I get the following error.

> The popstudio.in page isn’t working
>   popstudio.in is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I have attached a screenshot, refer [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR3lC.png)

**Note:**

- This is WordPress based website.
- I have renamed the plugins folder and still the website was down.
- I have renamed the themes folder still the website was down.

Comment: have you checked the file permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Common Solutions for the `500 Internal Server Error`. 
 
The two most common causes of this error are a corrupted `.htaccess` file and exceeding your `server’s PHP memory limit`.

The `.htaccess` file in your WordPress directory can become corrupted after you install a plugin or make another change to your WordPress site. The fix is simple. All you need to do is create a new `.htaccess` file. 
PHP memory limit issues often occur as the result of a poorly-coded plugin running on your site or a site that’s grown considerably over time and is using too many plugins. You’ll begin to exceed the `PHP memory limits` set by your hosting provider once either of these things happen. The result is a `500 internal server error`.

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 is a very generic error message. The information you're providing is not enough for someone here to help you.
The first place you want to look at is the log file. On an Apache server it is a file called error_log in the directory of your site.
You can check if your .htaccess file is properly configured.
Otherwise get in touch with your web host support!
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete (after make a backup) the .htaccess file on the root path of the site? If it work, just resaved permalinks from the back-office after that.

Most of the 500 errors on WordPress are due to a problem with this file (corrupted, rights problem ...).

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp-config.php and update it

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Make sure that once you have found your issue, to return it back to 'false'. Just as a security 'best practice'.